# How to plot event value in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I'm having trouble with seemingly simple task.
I have event "level_completed" with numeric parameter "value". I would like to see how many events per each value there is. Ideally, in a graph with x axis being "value" and y axis the event count with that parameter.

Can't seem to get it working in free form or any other exploration technique

I already tried all the techniques, created dimension for "value" parameter and any combination of segment / dimensions I could think of.